# Can a cell display data from 2 different areas?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm working on something just now that requires info from different excel sheets, here goes...

sheet 1 has 2 cells, cell a is a drop down with a choice of "unique" and "team"
Where "unique" is chosen, I want cell b to display the data from a seperate workbook
Where "team" is chosen, I want cell b to display the data from a cell on the same sheet

is this possible? does it even make sense?

Al

Comment: yes, it is possible. if it makes sense is upp to you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)